# Example of a smooth 'step'-function that is constant below 0 and constant above 1

Tags: real-analysis, functions, examples-counterexamples, distribution-theory, smooth-functions

I need an infinitely smooth non-decreasing function $\ f(x)$, that
$$f(x)=0\quad\forall x\leq 0,$$
$$f(x)=1\quad\forall x\geq 1,$$
and all its derivatives in $x=0$ and $x=1$ are $0$.

I found that I can't present any such function, what makes me confused. I know many examples of smooth finite hat-function, such as $e^{1/{(x-1)x}}$, but I still can't make it useful to create that step.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Recall that $$f(t) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
e^{-1/t} & t >0\\
0 & t \leq 0\\
\end{array}\right.$$
is smooth. Then $g(t) = \frac{f(t)}{f(t)+f(1-t)}$ is smooth, is equal to $1$ for $t \geq 1$, and equal to $0$ for $t \leq 0$.

This is the standard construction; you can probably find it in most any intro book to smooth manifolds, for instance, in their discussion on bump functions.

Comment: Lost my way in broad daylight. Thank you!

Comment: Could somebody point me to any book that actually discusses this function? Or similar functions. Some basic "Math for engineers" book preferred...

Comment: @math Maybe you could look in the reference of the Wikis: [Non-analytic smooth function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function) and [Bump function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function).

Answer (score 3):

How about using the Standardmollifier and massage it a bit:

\begin{align}
f(x) = \begin{cases} 0& \text{ if } x\leq 0\\ e^{1+\frac{-1}{1-(x-1)^2}}& \text{ if }0<x<1 \\1 & \text{ if }x\geq 1\end{cases}
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

My version of step-smooth function with infinite count of zero derivatives is

\begin{align}
f(x) = \begin{cases} 0& x\leq 0\\ \frac{1}{2} \left(\tanh \left(\frac{k (2 x-1)}{2 \sqrt{(1-x) x}}\right)+1\right)& 0<x<1 \\1 & x\geq 1\end{cases}
\end{align}

where $k$ is derivative at $x=1/2$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer by @user98602, you could use as example a piecewise version of the function $\frac{1}{1+\exp((2x-1)/(x^2-x))}$, which details could be found in [this question I did](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4720147/909869):
$$r(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+\exp\left(\dfrac{2x-1}{x^2-x}\right)\dfrac{\left(1+\text{sgn}(1-x)\right)}{\left(1+\text{sgn}(x)\right)}}$$

will make the trick, in principle. But caution must be taken since as could be seen the function $r(x)$ is undefined at the points $x=\{0,\ 1\}$ (something similar happened in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4730052/909869)), so to keep smoothness a piecewise definition is mandatory:
$$q(x)=\begin{cases}0,\quad x\leq 0\\ 1,\quad x\geq 1\\ \dfrac{1}{1+\exp\left(\dfrac{2x-1}{x^2-x}\right)},\ \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Also be aware that since this function behave as [flat function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_function) so by its nature is an example of [non-analytic smooth functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function), as also are [smooth bump functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) (this is why I edit one of your original tags).

You could see these functions in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vgnxfzwpy8):

[image: Desmos examples]