# Is the following statement regarding the equality of differentiable functions true?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Apologies if the phrasing is poor..

If we have two functions **f** and **g** with the same domain **X**, is the following statement correct:

If there is exists a point **a** within **X** such that **$f^n$(a)** = **$g^n$(a)** for all integers n > 0, then **f**(x) = **g**(x) for all x in **X**? Basically if there is a point where you know the derivitaves, of all order, are equal for both functions, does that mean the functions are identical across the domain?

If so - what is the proof? Thanks!

Comment: Counterexamples: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/846743/42969

Answer (score 2):

If **X** is $\mathbb R$, then the canonical counter-example is $f(x)=0$ everywhere, and $g(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ (with $g(0)=0$). Both functions have the property that the derivatives of all orders are zero at $x=0$.

If **X** is $\mathbb C$, however, this counterexample doesn't work, because $g$ has an [essential singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_singularity) at $x=0$. And in fact if **X** is $\mathbb C$, then $f$ and $g$ must be identical. For a proof of this, consult a textbook on complex analysis.

Comment: Ahh great thanks - this feels counter intuitive but I can't argue with that. Do you know anywhere I can find the proof for the domain in C?

Comment: Google "complex analysis" -- there's plenty of material out there. Briefly, all derivatives of the function $h=f-g$ are zero at **a**; in $\mathbb C$ (but not in $\mathbb R$), this guarantees that $h$ is everywhere zero. This has to do with the fact that in $\mathbb C$, a differentiable function has a unique Taylor series about every point.