# Problem about the construction of a smooth function

Tags: smooth-functions

I need to construct a function $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, such that
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{aligned}
&0,\quad x\leqslant 0,\\
&x,\quad x\geqslant 1.
\end{aligned}\right.$$
I already know that we can construct some smooth functions using something like $e^{-\frac{1}{x}}$, but I don't know how to do this one, can anyone give me some help?

Comment: Try constructing a function $g \in C^{\infty}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ such that $$g(x)=\left\{\begin{aligned}
&0,\quad x\leqslant 0,\\
&1,\quad x\geqslant 1.
\end{aligned}\right.$$ Then $xg(x)$ gives you your desired function.

Comment: Exactly. The so-called cutoff function, right?

Comment: A smooth bump function with support $(0,1)$ will have as its integral a smooth step function. Alternatively, consider [MSE Question 846743](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/846743/example-of-a-smooth-step-function-that-is-constant-below-0-and-constant-above).

Comment: @Shiva I tried your idea and it works, but the transition has a waving-like behavior. I tried by integrating a smooth cut-off function and it works without the waving (first and second derivatives kept their signs unchanged during the transitions). I added as an answer.

Comment: in [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4738961/909869) someone named @RaymondManzoni show an approximation that could be useful if you drop accuracy: $$f(x)=\dfrac{x}{1-e^{-8x}}$$ Its a sigmoid curve integrated, so is not exactly zero for negative values naither $x$ for possitive ones, but fit them quite accurately.

Comment: you could try some by integrating some cummulative distribution functions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully got your question, but I believe you are looking something like this function:
$$h(x)=\begin{cases} 0,\quad x\leq -\frac18 \\ x,\quad x\geq \frac18\\
\int\limits_{-\frac18}^x \frac{1}{1+\exp\left(\frac{32u}{64u^2-1}\right)}\ du,\ \text{otherwise}
 \end{cases}$$

which makes a smooth transition from $f(x)=0$ into $f(x)=x$.

I built it following the method shown in Wikipedia for [smooth Bump functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function).

You could see the function on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gigouzggbw):
[image: Desmos example]

---

*Added later*

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4739059/909869) it is found a series expansion for a similar function.

Answer (score 0):

Asking a [different question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4835130/909869) I found that there is a simple smooth version of the ramp function named in Wikipedia as [Softplus function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)#Softplus):

$$f(x) = \ln(1+e^x)$$

Achieves what you are aiming to do (you just need to displace and scale it - [as example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+ln%281%2Be%5E%288x-4%29%29%2C+from+x%3D-1+to+2) $f(8x-4)$), and it is smooth since its derivative is the [Logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function).

[image: plot]

Also, this function could be approximated by:
$$\ln(1+e^x) \approx \begin{cases} \frac{x}{1-e^{-\frac{x}{\ln(2)}}},\quad x\neq 0\\ \ln(2),\quad x=0\end{cases}$$

as could be seen in their [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+ln%281%2Be%5Ex%29%2C+x%2F%281-e%5E%28-x%2Fln%282%29%29%29):

[image: comparison of the plots]

You could find other approximations in this Wikipedia page: [Rectifier functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)#Softplus).

Comment: I found and even better alternativeba the end of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4838311/909869)