# Checking if functions are well defined Mollifiers kernels (Test functions / Bump functions)

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions, convolution, smooth-functions, schwartz-space

**Are these functions well defined [Mollifiers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier) kernels? Why? Why not?**

*I have found that these functions are also called [test functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaces_of_test_functions_and_distributions) and [smooth bump functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function).*

---

**Update: Since I am particularly interested on the $f_1(x)$ case, in the answers to [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4730052/909869) people have proved in very different and interesting ways that $f_1(x)$ is smooth when defined piecewise in order to avoid the undefined points $x = \{-1,\ 0,\ 1\}$.**

**So for the current question what is left to prove (if I am not mistaken), is it if is possible to calculate the convolution integral of the Mollifier application without solving the issues at these undefined points with zero-measure (so, using $f_1(x)$ just like is defined here), or if conversely, it is required the piecewise definition used in the mentioned question.**

**For the other examples the same situation will follow, since $f_1(x)$ the worst or equal case scenario (again, If I am not mistaken).**

---

Consider the following functions as $$F_i(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{f_i(x)}{I_i},\quad x<|1| \\ 0,\quad |x|\geq 1\end{cases}$$ where $I_i$ is a normalizing constant such as $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} F_i(x)\ dx=1$ and $f_i(x)$ are the following functions:

1. $$f_1(x)=\frac{1}{1+\exp\left(\frac{1-2|x|}{x^2-|x|}\right)}$$ which resembles the lobes of the [Fabius function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabius_function) and [Rvachëv function](https://oeis.org/A288163) (which fulfills $R'(x)=2R(2x+1)-2R(2x-1)$), as could be seen in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/k0jamvjlgt) through the approximation shown in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/285939/82135).
2. $$f_2(x)=\frac{1}{1+\exp\left(\frac{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\left(1-2|x|\right)}{x^2-|x|}\right)}$$ which have "almost" straight-line "sides".
3. $$f_3(x)=\frac{1}{1+\exp\left(\frac{2\left(1-2|x|\right)}{x^2-|x|}\right)}$$ which look it have an "almost [flat function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_function) top": I wasn't able to prove it, but by inspection they look indeed flat, and as also $f_1(x)$ both looks are not analytic at $x=0$ which is a good syntom, as can be seen in [Wolfram-Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2F%281%2Bsum%5B%28%281-2%7Cx%7C%29%2F%28x%5E2-%7Cx%7C%29%29%5Ek%2Fk%21%2Ck%2C0%2C10%5D%29&lang=es).
4. $$f_4(x)=\exp\left(\frac{\ln(4)x^2}{|x|-1}\right)$$
5. $$f_5(x)=\exp\left(\frac{\ln(8)x^2}{x^2-1}\right)$$
6. $$f_6(x)=\exp\left(\frac{2(2-\sqrt{2})\ln(2)x^2}{\sqrt{|x|}-1}\right)$$

All these functions fulfills $f_i\left(\pm\frac12\right)=\frac12$, $f_i(\pm 1)\to 0$, and $f_i(0)\to 1$ ("arrows" meaning "tendency under the limit" sense).

You could see these functions [here on Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dljum7xhq5).

[image: example functions]

I am trying to understand Mollifiers through these examples, which all of them "look smooth" but some have "avoidable issues", like undefined values but where the function is continuous (like $f_1(x)$ at $x=0$ - check [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4729476/909869)), or their derivatives rises Dirac's delta functions because of the absolute values but that are avoidable by defining the same functions piecewise (like in [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4730052/909869)), so I am trying to figure out if smoothness (being class $C^\infty$) is hold or not on these cases.

As example, $f_1(x)$ could be constructed as is [shown here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function#Examples) by choosing $f(x)=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)\theta(x)$ with $\theta(x)$ the [Heaviside step function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function), then making $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(1-x)}$ and then lets $f_1(x)=g\left(\frac{x-a}{b-a}\right)\cdot g\left(\frac{d-x}{d-c}\right)$ with $a=-1,\ b=c=0,\ d=1$, as could be seen in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1h7kvjc9ae).
Moreover, a simular construction is used in [this answer in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/328876/909869) to built an example of a [smooth transition function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function#Smooth_transition_functions) so in the case of $f_1(x)$, in principle, the points were could be some issues should be $x=\{-1;\ 0;\ 1\}$.

I am specialy worried about the behaviour at $x\to 0$: at the edges $\partial x =\{-1;\ 1\}$ I know that since how I defined $F(x)$ some of these functions will hold smoothness there: $$\lim\limits_{x\to\partial x^\pm} \frac{d^n}{dx^n}F_i(x)=0\quad n\geq 0,\ n\in\mathbb{Z}_{+}$$
but for others as is showed on Desmos it could be some problems at the edges $\partial x$: I don't know if it is a Desmos' software issue or indeed $f_1(x)$ lost smoothness at higher derivatives [as example](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fqtkvyhudo).

Also, I am not really sure if the definition of $F(x)$ as stated is equivalent to consider $\frac{f_i(x)}{I_i}\theta(1-x^2)$, neither if all these "situations" could be avoided since [Mollifiers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier) kernels are evaluated under an integral sign in convolution operations, so in principle, a zero-measure point shouldn't have an impact in the final value, but this is not necessarily true for distributions (just think of the [Dirac's Delta function](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_de_Dirac#Propiedades) example), so I am trying to understand what criterion applies on each example. As counterexample, you could check in [Wolfram-Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int_%7B-inf%7D%5Einf+unitstep%281-x%5E2%29%2F%281%2Be%5E%28%281-2%7Cx%7C%29%2F%28x%5E2-%7Cx%7C%29%29%29*dx) that $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty F_1(x)\ dx=1$, even when $F_1(x=0)$ is [undefined](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=evaluate+unitstep%281-x%5E2%29%2F%281%2Be%5E%28%281-2%7Cx%7C%29%2F%28x%5E2-%7Cx%7C%29%29%29+at+x%3D0&lang=es).

As example, if the problems of $f_1(x)$ at $x=0$ and at $\partial x$ are avoidable or "ficticious", meaning it is indeed smooth, then it should be a [Mollifier](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier#Definition) since fulfill:

1. $F_1(x)$ is compact suported
2. $\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}F_1(x)\ dx=1$ with $I_1=1$
3. $\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{1}{\epsilon}F_1\left(\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right)\to\delta(x)$ as you can [see in Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5ebkkxdg6r).

So, finding out what is happening at these critical points $x=\{-1;\ 0;\ 1\}$ will determine if $f_1(x)$ could be used as a Mollifier or not:
$$\Phi(q)(x)=q(x)\circledast F_i(x)=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}q(y)F_i(x-y)\ dy=\int\limits_{|x|<1}q(x-y)F_i(y)\ dy$$

**Bonus track:** the functions $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{1+\exp\left(\frac{n\left(1-2|x|\right)}{x^2-|x|}\right)}$$ becomes the [rectangular function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function): Does exist a finite $n$ where it lost its smoothness?

Comment: Thanks to L'Hospital's rule, if you can show that $\lim_{x \to 1^-} f^{(n)}(x) = 0$ for every $n$, it will follow that $f$ is infinitely differentiable at $1$.  As a warmup, try $f(x) = e^{-1/(1-x)}$.  Prove by induction that $f^{(n)}(x)$ is of the form $g_n(x) e^{-1/(1-x)}$ where $g_n$ is a rational function.  Since exponentials grow faster than polynomials, it follows that $f^{(n)}(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 1^-$.  Similar techniques should work for the functions here, though the algebra could be messier.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for commenting, its interesting. I tried to did something in the direction you point in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4382260/909869) but I got anyway many "dislikes": the problem as I saw it in this question examples, is that many will rise problems at $x\to 0$ since is were will be centered the dirac's delta functions of the derivatives of $|x|$ as also some get a division by zero in the exponential exponent.

Comment: I would be interested in going into researching this problem with you. How to contact?

Comment: @HopefulWhitepiller Thanks for getting interested. I new to this but I tried to made a chat room in this [link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/146776/mollifier-examples)

Comment: @HopefulWhitepiller Hi. I don't know why the chat room link now is missing. I have added some comments about what I have learned about $f_1(x)$ in other questions like [this one answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4729357/909869) and [this one open](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4730052/909869): if the last one answer is affirmative, I think $f_1(x)$ and related could still be used as mollifiers. Did you were able to take the time to work on them?

Comment: @NateEldredge You meaning like the demonstration shown in [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function#The_function_is_smooth)?? It don't mention L'Hopital

Comment: @Joako: Yeah, there are certainly different ways to do it.  At the lowest level, they all end up relying on pretty much the same limit computations.

Comment: @NateEldredge In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4731325/909869) someone used a different approach that looks simpler at first glance, so much, that I don't know if it is indeed right.

Comment: I just saw you linked this question from [the other one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4730052/293177). It seems to me you should be able to easily reuse [the answer I gave there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4737361/293177) directly at least for cases 1-3. For 4-6 I'm not so sure, because the numerator in the exponent is of higher degree than the denominator, but you should be able to find patterns similar to what I explored in my answer and apply them in 4-6, too.

Comment: @Al.G. Both questions aims to something slightly different: in the other one I was asking if fixing $f_1(x)$ by a piecewise definition would help to keep smoothness. In this one, there is no fix for $f_1(x)$ at $x=0$, so I am trying to understand if when using Mollifiers these non-zero measure points where the function is undefined are a problem that need to be previously fixed, or conversely, it doesn't matter because of being under a integration sign. I believe $f_1(x)$ to $f_3(x)$ should behave in the same way, and the following $f_4(x)$ to $f_3(x)$ also in the same way among them.